# Specify .constructor.name to be an arbitrary string

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I understand there is a way to have the `.constructor.name` be different from the variable the constructor is stored in

```js
var Foo = function Bar() {};
console.log(new Foo().constructor.name) // => Bar
```

I was wondering if there is a hacky way to set an object's `.constructor.name` to something that wouldn't be a valid JS function name, e.g. `"Hello::World"`.

Setting it directly doesn't seem to work:

```js
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.constructor.name = "Test"
console.log(new Foo().constructor.name) // => Foo
```

I've tried doing it with the `Function` constructor, but is uses `eval`, so the JS has to be valid despite being passed a string.

Comment: Is this just a science experiment, or are you trying to solve a higher level problem?

Comment: I'm writing a transpiler to JS and ideally would like to keep the original class names. I know I could just store a string in a custom field of every constructor, so this particular approach is more of an experiment.

Comment: Why can't you simply define the transpiled function using the original name? E.g. `def type SomeType {}` -> `class SomeType { ... }`

Comment: Well, the class name would print the same as the original code as well? Could you give an example?

Comment: @plalx In case `SomeType` is invalid in JS, e.g. it contains a namespace `Module::ClassName`. Replacing `::` with something also wouldn't work because the class name could be used as a string and be visible to the end user.

Comment: I would rather transpile the code using hard-coded values in that case. Overriding the name looks a bit silly and could not be wise IMO. Can't you just transpile all references of `Module::ClassName.toString()` or the equivalent to `'Module::ClassName'`? Granted, it requires good static analysis which you may not have though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prototype.constructor.name` is defined as non-writable, which means you can't just change it with an assignment.

```js
var Foo = function Bar() {};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo.prototype.constructor, 'name'))
```

But, as you can see, it is configureable, which means you can redefine it. I have no idea if this is wise, but you can do it like:

```js
var Foo = function Bar() {};

Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype.constructor, 'name', {value: "Test"})
console.log(new Foo().constructor.name)  // Test
```